# How do I convert a tensorflow model into a TensorRT optimized model using trt.TrtGraphConverterV2 (or other suggestion)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am stuck with a problem regarding TensorRT and Tensorflow.
I am using a NVIDIA jetson nano and I try to convert simple Tensorflow models into TensorRT optimized models.
I am using tensorflow 2.1.0 and python 3.6.9.
I try to use utilize t.his code sample from the [NVIDIA-guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#usage-example):

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(input_saved_model_dir=input_saved_model_dir)
converter.convert()
converter.save(output_saved_model_dir)
```

To test this, I took a simple example from the tensorflow website . To convert the model into an TensorRT-model, I save the model as a "savedModel" and the loaded it into the trt.TrtGraphConverterV2-function:

```
#https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
import os

#mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

#(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
#x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])


# create paths to save models
model_name = "simpleModel"
pb_model  = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),(model_name+"_pb")) 
trt_model = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),(model_name+"_trt")) 

if not os.path.exists(pb_model):
    os.mkdir(pb_model)

if not os.path.exists(trt_model):
    os.mkdir(trt_model)

tf.saved_model.save(model, pb_model)


# https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#usage-example
print("\nconverting to trt-model")
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(input_saved_model_dir=pb_model )
print("\nconverter.convert")
converter.convert()
print("\nconverter.save")
converter.save(trt_model)

print("trt-model saved under: ",trt_model)
```

When I run this code it saves the trt-optimized model,but the model cannot be used. When I load the model and try model.summary() for example it tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/al/Code/Benchmark_70x70/test-load-pb.py", line 45, in <module>
    model.summary()
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

This is the complete output of the converter script:

```
2020-04-01 20:38:07.395780: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:11.837436: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6
2020-04-01 20:38:11.879775: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer_plugin.so.6
2020-04-01 20:38:17.015440: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-04-01 20:38:17.054065: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.061718: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0 name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 computeCapability: 5.3
coreClock: 0.9216GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 3.87GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 23.84GiB/s
2020-04-01 20:38:17.061853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.061989: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.145546: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.252192: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.368195: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.433245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.433451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 20:38:17.433761: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.434112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.434418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.483529: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:98] Failed to find bogomips in /proc/cpuinfo; cannot determine CPU frequency
2020-04-01 20:38:17.504302: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x13e7b0f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-01 20:38:17.504407: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-04-01 20:38:17.713898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.714293: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x13de1210 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-01 20:38:17.714758: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA Tegra X1, Compute Capability 5.3
2020-04-01 20:38:17.715405: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.715650: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0 name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 computeCapability: 5.3
coreClock: 0.9216GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 3.87GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 23.84GiB/s
2020-04-01 20:38:17.715796: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.715941: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716057: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716174: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716252: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716311: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716687: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.716994: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:17.717111: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 20:38:17.736625: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:30.190208: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-01 20:38:30.315240: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-04-01 20:38:30.315482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-01 20:38:30.832895: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:31.002925: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:31.005861: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 32 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
2020-04-01 20:38:34.803674: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:319] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1786: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.

converting to trt-model
2020-04-01 20:38:37.808143: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libnvinfer.so.6

converter.convert
2020-04-01 20:38:39.618691: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:39.618842: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:55] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
2020-04-01 20:38:39.619224: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-04-01 20:38:39.712117: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:39.712437: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0 name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 computeCapability: 5.3
coreClock: 0.9216GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 3.87GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 23.84GiB/s
2020-04-01 20:38:39.712594: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:39.744930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.056630: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.153461: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.176047: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.214052: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.231552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 20:38:40.231927: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232388: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232587: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232618: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-01 20:38:40.232890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.233546: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.233761: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 32 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
2020-04-01 20:38:40.579950: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:841] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-04-01 20:38:40.580104: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   function_optimizer: Graph size after: 26 nodes (19), 43 edges (36), time = 179.825ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:40.580157: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 0.152ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:40.941994: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.942217: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:55] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.942412: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-04-01 20:38:40.943756: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.943916: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0 name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 computeCapability: 5.3
coreClock: 0.9216GHz coreCount: 1 deviceMemorySize: 3.87GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 23.84GiB/s
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944073: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944148: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944209: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944266: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944372: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944572: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944816: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944911: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-01 20:38:40.944993: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-01 20:38:40.945031: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-04-01 20:38:40.945059: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-01 20:38:40.945283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.945569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:948] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2020-04-01 20:38:40.945714: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 32 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
2020-04-01 20:38:41.037807: I tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/segment/segment.cc:460] There are 6 ops of 3 different types in the graph that are not converted to TensorRT: Identity, NoOp, Placeholder, (For more information see https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html#supported-ops).
2020-04-01 20:38:41.043736: I tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:636] Number of TensorRT candidate segments: 1
2020-04-01 20:38:41.046312: I tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/convert/convert_graph.cc:737] Replaced segment 0 consisting of 12 nodes by TRTEngineOp_0.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073078: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:841] Optimization results for grappler item: tf_graph
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073159: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 22 nodes (-4), 35 edges (-8), time = 14.454ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073188: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   layout: Graph size after: 22 nodes (0), 35 edges (0), time = 20.565ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073214: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 22 nodes (0), 35 edges (0), time = 5.644ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073238: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   TensorRTOptimizer: Graph size after: 11 nodes (-11), 14 edges (-21), time = 28.58ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073265: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 11 nodes (0), 14 edges (0), time = 2.904ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073289: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:841] Optimization results for grappler item: TRTEngineOp_0_native_segment
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073312: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 14 nodes (0), 15 edges (0), time = 2.875ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073335: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   layout: Graph size after: 14 nodes (0), 15 edges (0), time = 2.389ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073358: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 14 nodes (0), 15 edges (0), time = 2.834ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073382: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   TensorRTOptimizer: Graph size after: 14 nodes (0), 15 edges (0), time = 0.218ms.
2020-04-01 20:38:41.073405: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:843]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 14 nodes (0), 15 edges (0), time = 5.268ms.

converter.save
2020-04-01 20:38:46.730260: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1655] OP_REQUIRES failed at trt_engine_resource_ops.cc:183 : Not found: Container TF-TRT does not exist. (Could not find resource: TF-TRT/TRTEngineOp_0)
trt-model saved under:  /home/al/Code/Benchmark_70x70/simpleModel_trt
```

Comment: Please let me know if you find something helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for the response. It contains everything I need. 
To test the converter script, I ran the code in colab and it worked fine, so I guess I need to check my environment for errors.
Regarding the **model.summary()** issue:
As you pointed out correctly,it seems like methods from the Keras API are removed when converting the model. I especially needed the **model.predict()** method to use the new model for prediction. Luckily there are **other ways to run inference**. Additionaly to the one you posted, I found the one described in [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) and used it.
I summarized the whole example and explanations in this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/monkeyman85/e04e240cde74be48750d8160e078d5d7/convert_simplemodel_to_tensorrt_rev1.ipynb)

```
loaded = tf.saved_model.load('./model_trt')  # loading the converted model

print("The signature keys are: ",list(loaded.signatures.keys())) 
infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]

im_select = 0 # choose train-image you want to classify
labeling = infer(tf.constant(train_images[im_select],dtype=float))['LastLayer']   ## Here, the Image classification happens; we need the name of the last layer we defined in the beginning


#Display result
print("Image ",im_select," is classified as a ",class_names[int(tf.argmax(labeling,axis=1))] )
plt.imshow(train_images[im_select])
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the conversion  has  been successful, 
I have tried using both the .pb files from Keras & TensorRT. 
Below is the sample code

```
saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(
    'path to trt converted model') # path to keras .pb or TensorRT .pb
#for layer in saved_model_loaded.keras_api.layers:

graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(
    graph_func)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

#convert to tensors
input_tensors = tf.cast(x_test, dtype=tf.float32)

output = frozen_func(input_tensors[:1])[0].numpy()
print(output)
```

***Note: I have tried both of the model from keras & TensorRT and the result is the same.***

Regarding the ***model.summary()*** Error,  It seems that once the model is converted, it removes some of the methods like ***.summary()***
But you can use Tensorboard as an alternative if you want to check the graph from tensorRT converted model
Below is the sample code

```
import argparse
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
%load_ext tensorboard
from tensorflow.python.platform import app
from tensorflow.python.summary import summary

def import_to_tensorboard(model_dir, log_dir):
  """View an imported protobuf model (`.pb` file) as a graph in Tensorboard.

  Args:
    model_dir: The location of the protobuf (`pb`) model to visualize
    log_dir: The location for the Tensorboard log to begin visualization from.

  Usage:
    Call this function with your model location and desired log directory.
    Launch Tensorboard by pointing it to the log directory.
    View your imported `.pb` model as a graph.
  """

  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], model_dir)

    pb_visual_writer = summary.FileWriter(log_dir)
    pb_visual_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    print("Model Imported. Visualize by running: "
          "tensorboard --logdir={}".format(log_dir))
```

Call the function

```
import_to_tensorboard('path to trt model', '/logs/')
```

Open the Tensorboard

```
%tensorboard --logdir='path to logs'
```

Let me know if this help.

Comment: Where does `convert_variables_to_constants_v2()` come from?

Answer (score -1):

'''

steps to convert tensorflow model to tensor RT model

1. Load the model (. h5 or. hdf5) using model.load_weights(.h5_file_dir)
2. Save the model using tf.saved_model.save(your_model, destn_dir)
   It will save the model in .pb format with assets and variables folder, keep those as it is.

Use the Linux machine to convert .pb model to tensorRT
while converting remember just give path for the folder where the pb file and other folders(assets and variables) exists.
then start converting.

'''